# Problem with help div inside table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table of roles that has checkboxes with access or not. I need a help-button on the right most column that shows information for the role using JQuery Dialog. For some reason the dialog only shows every second time.

Below is the code I use:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<%foreach (Role role in ViewData["Roles"] as List<Role>)
  { %>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            <%=role.RoleName %>
        </td>
        <td width="70%">
            <%=Html.CheckBox(role.RoleName, Model.IsInRole(role.LoweredRoleName)) %>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
        <%if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(role.Description))
          { %>
            <%Html.RenderPartial("Help", new KeyValuePair<string, string>(role.RoleName, role.Description)); %>
        <%} %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

Help.aspx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<KeyValuePair<string, string>>" %>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#<%=Model.Key.Replace(" ", "") %>').dialog(); return false;">
    <img border="0" src="../../Content/Images/help_icon.gif" alt="?"/>
</a>
<div id="<%=Model.Key.Replace(" ", "") %>" title="<%=Model.Key %>" style="display:none;">
    <%=Model.Value %>
</div>
```

Comment: Every second click or every second row? I can't tell if you are having a rendering issue or a client side issue.

Comment: @ahsteele it is a client side issue. The dialog is there but it is empty. If I click the help link the checkbox disappears and the dialog pops up empty.

Comment: @ahsteele every second click. I use the same code above but with only 2 rows and there it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

A call to $(foo).dialog() will initialize a dialog instance and will auto-open the dialog by default. If you want to reuse a dialog, the easiest way is to disable the "auto-open" option with: $(foo).dialog({ autoOpen: false }) and open it with $(foo).dialog('open')

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#overview and 
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

But I'd suggest to use something like http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/ instead. ClueTip has options to be opened via click and stay until closed, so you can choose between hover and click activation. It is also extremely easy to get content via AJAX, so you don't have to load page full of information that user may never click to see.

Comment: Thanks. But I think you are focusing on the wrong thing. It works just perfect to use this code in other places. But in this particular table it does not work. I guess this is a HTML/CSS issue, not JS or what jquery-plugin I use.